# How to crawl webpage's rest request after clicking a button?

Tags: html, selenium, rest, web, web-crawler

I am new to web crawl and only have some experience on crawling static sites. I have following questions for my new project:

### Background

On this page: https://leetcode.com/contest/biweekly-contest-65/ranking/1/, a window that contains some code would pop up after you click on each file button.

### Objective

My goal is to crawl code from all file buttons on this page and save them in local.

### Challenge

I am not sure how to get code from all file buttons using web crawler.

### What I have tried

I checked from inspection that by clicking the file button everytime, it generates a GET Request to api. For example, if you click the first (top left) button, it calls server with https://leetcode.com/api/submissions/586506999/ which contains the code I need in json format.

So looks like as long as i can gather all submission ids (586506999), i could receive all codes from this page, each in a json file.

However, I am not sure how to let the crawler get the subsmission id (586506999). I checked from the html looks the id isnt there, so a bit confused on how this id is generated and how to retrieve all of them on this page.

Also I am open to other strategies that can achieve my objective.

Thanks in advance